# Scala covariance when doing pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, covariance

I've been writing a toy symbolic algebra system.

```scala
  trait Expr[A]
  trait Func[A, B] extends Expr[A => B] with (Expr[A] => Expr[B])
  case class Apply[A, B](f: Func[A, B], x: Expr[A]) extends Expr[B]
  val fx: Expr[Int] = ???
  fx match {
    case Apply(f, x) => 
  }
```

The inferred type for `f` in the `case` clause is `Func[Any, Int]` and the type for `x` is `Any`. If I change the signature of `Func[A, B]` to `Func[-A, +B]`, it is inferred as `Func[Nothing, Int]`. It seems to me that the Scala compiler is treating an invariant type parameter as a covariant one.

This is not what I want. I would like it to be inferred as `∃T, f :: Func[T, B]` and `x :: T`.

Is the Scala compiler able to do this (using an existential type?)

Comment: How are you arriving at the conclusion that *The inferred type for `f` in the case clause is Func`[Any, Int]`* ? Currently it is a match error.

Comment: It is provided by IntelliJ IDEA.